# Отображение текста в Textarea с конца

Tags: html, textarea

Нужно сделать textarea так, чтобы сначала отображался текст, который находится в самом конце, а потом чтобы уже самому можно было пролистать вверх.

Comment: Текстария при этом должна быть какой высоты?

Comment: 12 rows в ней сейчас стоит, нужно чтобы текст, который из 20 строчек, загружался с конца, а размер так и оставался

Comment: `textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170670/how-do-i-set-textarea-scroll-bar-to-bottom-as-a-default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
// Просто для примера заполняем, чтобы не занимало место
var lines = '';
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) lines += '\r';
$('textarea').html(lines + 'Bottom text here');

// Находим нужную текстарию и скролим на её конец
var textarea = $('textarea');
textarea.scrollTop(textarea[0].scrollHeight - textarea.height());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea rows="12"></textarea>
```